# Was the early calculus inconsistent?

Tags: lo.logic, ho.history-overview, nonstandard-analysis

This question does NOT concern the RIGOR, or lack thereof, of the early calculus. Rather the question is of its CONSISTENCY.

George Berkeley wrote in 1734 with reference to the early calculus that such a method is "a most inconsistent way of arguing, and such as would not be allowed in Divinity". This passage is quoted by William Dunham in 2004. Dunham concludes: "Bishop Berkeley had made his point. Although the results of the calculus seemed to be valid ... none of this mattered if the foundations were rotten". See page 72 of http://books.google.co.il/books?id=QnXSqvTiEjYC&source=gbs_navlinks_s

On the other hand, Peter Vickers in 2007 challenged "The ubiquitous assertion that the early calculus of Newton and Leibniz was an inconsistent theory" at http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/3477/ (soon to appear in book form at Oxford University Press), and concluded that this only holds in a limited sense and "can only be imputed to a small minority of the relevant community".

Was the early calculus consistent as far as most practitioners were concerned, as Vickers contended, or was it a most inconsistent way of arguing, as did Berkeley and Dunham?

Note 1. Berkeley claimed that calculus was based on an inconsistency that can be expressed in modern notation as $(dx\not=0)\wedge(dx=0)$.  Thus he was using the term "inconsistent" in much the same sense it is used in modern logic.

Note 2. For a closely related thread, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445166/is-mathematical-history-written-by-the-victors

Note 3. There is a related thread at the history SE: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3301

Comment: subjective and argumentative?

Comment: It's not clear to me "early calculus" was formal enough to talk about whether or not it was consistent.  There were things people *did*, so you can talk about the actions of people being consistent or inconsistent makes sense on a behavioral level, but by that standard they probably were fairly consistent. 

Comment: I prefer this question to the previous one, although we are now firmly in the realm of HPS when we try to understand what Berkeley meant by "inconsistency" (or for that matter, in what venues Vickers finds this assertion "ubiquitous").

Comment: Berkeley is of course famous to most people for his ontology, not his views on calculus/fluxions.

Comment: @Ryan Budney: Authors like Boyer, Grabiner, as well as authors of calculus textbooks routinely claim such "inconsistency" ($dx\not=0$, $dx=0$, Q.E.D.). It could be that the early calculus was not "formal enough" as you suggest, but what do we make of such repeated claims in the literature? To illustrate a concept from the early calculus that was clearly inconsistent, consider Nieuwentijt's idea of an infinitesimal of the form $\frac{1}{\infty}$ that was supposed to be nilpotent. This is inconsistent by any modern standard, unlike Leibnizian calculus where the question is debatable as per above

Comment: At the root of this question is an implicit and very ahistorical assumption that the word "consistent" was used by Bishop Berkeley in the same sense that it is used by modern logicians.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: Berkeley is certainly taken seriously by philosophers, and perhaps more so than by mathematicians.  Still, reliance on Berkeley's analysis of the calculus to label the latter "inconsistent" is ubiquitous in the history of math literature.  If you are serious about questioning this, I can try to provide further references in addition to Boyer and Grabiner.

Comment: I've occasionally wondered about this too, and here is how I made it precise in my mind.  Many arguments in calculus were rather vague before the advent of deltas and epsilons, so it seems possible that there was a computation for which two different vague arguments gave different answers, or a vague argument which gave the right answer for one computation but the wrong answer in another.  Did this ever happen?

Comment: The question is not clear, as the word "consistent" has multiple meanings.  One must separately consider consistency of techniques and consistency of the arguments used to justify techniques.  The practitioners of the early calculus viewed it as a set of legitimate methods for obtaining results that agreed with other methods and physical observation.  They also treated certain quantities as both zero and non-zero in proofs, which is inconsistent with modern proof practice...

Comment: ... Thus, the early practitioners found their techniques consistent, and modern commentators find their use of zero/non-zero quantities in proofs inconsistent.

Comment: I find the question very interesting, and I am looking forward to reading answers posted by those with expertise in mathematical history.

Comment: Yes, I think too that the question is much more interesting as the first one about the "victors". Yet I am still not convinced of the premise: is the claim that the early calculus was inconsistent
really "ubiquitous"? I don't know the authors that Katz is mentioning 
to substantiate his claim: Boyer, Grabiner? I don't read either a lot of calculus textbook. It seems to me that the naive, uniformed, dominant view about mathematicians was that the corpus of results
of the calculus pioneers (Descartes, Pascal, Fermat, Newton, Leibniz, and you can continue with the Bernoulli(s), perhaps Euler)..  

Comment: ... contains only true, if not rigorously proved at that time, results. And a set of true results can not be, by any sense of the term, "inconsistent". So really, I am not sure what the question is about... 

Comment: @Ben Brown: You wrote above that "They also treated certain quantities as both zero and non-zero in proofs, which is inconsistent with modern proof practice...Thus, the early practitioners found their techniques consistent, and modern commentators find their use of zero/non-zero quantities in proofs inconsistent." Berkeley precisely alleged that authors like Leibniz treated certain quantities as both zero and nonzero. But is Berkeley's criticism of Leibniz accurate?


Comment: @Joël: You wrote that "Yet I am still not convinced of the premise: is the claim that the early calculus was inconsistent really "ubiquitous"? I don't know the authors that Katz is mentioning to substantiate his claim: Boyer, Grabiner?" Grabiner is a historian. She wrote: "As Berkeley put it, the quantity we have called h 'might have signified either an increment or nothing. But then, which of these soever you make it signify, you must argue CONSISTENTLY with such its signification'. See http://www.maa.org/pubs/Calc_articles/ma002.pdf The implication is the early practices were inconsistent. 

Comment: @Lee Mosher: you speak of a "very ahistorical assumption that the word 'consistent' was used by Bishop Berkeley in the same sense that it is used by modern logicians".  Actually, it is exactly the same sense.  Berkeley claimed the calculus was based on the inconsistency $(dx\not=0)\wedge(dx=0)$.

Comment: [deleted comment made when reading the wrong question]

Comment: @Yemon: While I clearly perceive the sarcasm, I am not actually sure what you mean. The title of this question does not contain the word "history". Are you referring to the SE thread on the "victors"? Just to be perfectly clear, I am a great fan of Weierstrass in general and epsilontics in particular. I just don't think a post-Weierstrassian spin accompanied by denigration of the early masters does justice to the history you find fascinating.

Comment: Mikhail, yes I was reading the wrong thread title in my browser. Actually I agree with your last sentence, I have just never come across such denigration throughout my education as an analyst - which was as classical as you could imagine - and my teaching of the subject. FWIW I think the early approaches were incomplete (you have argued well against inconsistency) and that W's approach provides a fix, not nec. the only fix.

Comment: I also would care rather more what e.g. Thomas Korner or Jean Bourgain or Fedja Nazarov say about infinitesimals than anything Connes may have said in an attempt to be aphoristic, but perhaps that's just me :)

Comment: @Yemon: Could you provide some links on what Korner, Bourgain, and Nazarov may have said about infinitesimals?

Comment: It was, I'm afraid, purely hypothetical. But I picked three people who have done concrete harmonic/Fourier analysis of a high standard, certainly fluent in epsilons and deltas, who I suspect actually think in a more intuitive way. (Bourgain is just in there in case we are for some reason concentrating on what Fields Medallists may have brought down from Mount Sinai)

Comment: @Yemon: you seem to be referring rather to mount Bur-sur-Yvette :-) Speaking of which, I had some discussions with [Pierre Cartier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Cartier_(mathematician)) who is very favorably disposed to infinitesimals both historical and modern (and his written about this). But I am not sure why discussions of the shortcomings of the coverage of the early calculus tend inevitably to turn into a court case on nonstandard analysis, as if ackowledging the bias of post-Weierstrassian historians will necessarily prove A. Robinson's point. The two issues are separate issues.

Comment: I agree they are separate issues, which is why I get a bit frustrated when Connes's comments - which always sounded to me like he was not thinking seriously but aiming for aphorism - are brought up. I might even argue that people addressing the infinitesimals of Leibniz and Euler by bringing up NSA are themselves drifting into Whig history...

Comment: @Yemon: this is a potentially valid criticism. The answer to the criticism is carefully distinguishing between syntactic and semantic issues, as has been discussed elsewhere. At some point one has to confront the question as to which point of you is more meaningful on Leibniz: the one that claims that his infinitesimals were logically inconsistent and were finally swept away by Weierstrass, or the one that finds modern proxies to his Law of Continuity and Law of Homogeneity in the context of modern infinitesimal theories. The editors of Erkenntnis did not find obvious Whig flaws with our piece

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Coming back to the B.Berkeley critics, there is a common denominator of all known getarounds, both the two mainstream ones (Wstrass and NSA) and exotic ones like the SDG interpretation.

That is, one considers an extension - call it $R^+$ - of the true reals R and a map 
$R^+ \to R\cup \{\infty\}$ - call it the valuation map. For instance,

1) $R^+$ consists of all convergent infinite real sequences and the valuation map is the 
`` taking the limit'' map

2) $R^+$ is a nonstandard extension of $R$ and the valuation map is the ``standard part'' map ($\infty$  for infinitely large objects)

3) Nilpotent or any other applicable exotics.

It occurs that the evaluation map cannot be a homomorphism, it always lacks something. For instance the value of a non-0 infinitesimal is 0, the value of its inverse is $\infty$, but $0\cdot \infty=1$ makes little sense in $R$.

This is I believe the only sound way to view the medieval controversies around infinitesimals. That is, accept that a non-0 infinitesimal is not equal to the real number 0, it just has the value 0. Maybe, a devoted scholar of Leibnizz, Euler, etc. (although there is no much of etc. after Euler!) can find a support of this point of view.

Obviously, a modern mathematician would ask for either a concrete mathematically defined model of both $R^+$ and the valuation map - and the two mainstream such models are listed above, with perhaps more yet to come under category 3 - or at least to set it up in the form of calculus of propositions, with rigorous rules of inference albeit w/o a fixed interpretation of objects.

Vladimir Kanovei

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir.  Indeed, Leibniz provided consistent rules of inference in terms of his Transcendental law of homogeneity ("discard the negligible term"), without of course providing any interpretation of the number system itself (which had to await Hewitt, Los, and Robinson).

Comment: There can be no such valuation map in Synthethic Differential geometry, and neither is it the case that the smooth real line is an extension of "true reals" (whatever those are supposed to be), at least I do not see how that could be, since the smooth real line is not even Cauchy complete.

Comment: There is a more down-to-earth construction of "nonstandard" reals with nilpotent infinitesimals by Paolo Giordano. I believe in his construction there is a valuation map. Perhaps Paolo could comment.

Comment: This is not the only sound way to view the controversy. Another sensible way is to go intuitionistic. The controversy is then resolved by realizing that (a) not all infinitesimals are zero and (b) given any infinitesimal, it is not the case that it is distinct from zero. There is no valuation map, or a sharp distinction between "standard" reals and infinitesimals, only weird (but sound!) intuitionistic sort of half-existence of infinitesimals.

Comment: Old habits die hard ;-)

Comment: >>given any infinitesimal, it is not the case that it is distinct from zero.

This is so funny! I mean, you claim in particular that any argument starting from 
"let e be a small positive infinitesimal number (hence non-0)". 
is wrong from the beginning? 
What then about the Euler factorization of sin which starts from an inf. large number i and then involves infinitesimals like 1/i - is it "not the case" that 1/i is definitely "distinct from zero"?   

Comment: @Vladimir: In SDG they have both kinds of infinitesimals if needed: the nilpotent ones and the invertible ones.  About 1/i it is certainly the case that it is positive and not merely that it is not the case that it is or isn't distinct from zero.

Comment: And those denoted as dx, dy etc, what sort are them of? Hardly nilpotent since second derivatives involve $dx^2=(dx)^2$. - Vladimir

Comment: I hope Andrej or somebody else knowledgeable about SDG comments on this, but awaiting their comment, it seems to me that they can arrange for nilpotency of any finite order one wishes.  I have the impression they can accomodate higher order differentials this way.

Comment: @Vladimir:  This does not contradict your point (or indeed any of the text of your latest comment), but one must be careful with $d^2y$, $dx^2$, and the like.  Second derivatives in Leibniz's notation don't work as well as first derivatives, because the chain rule $d^2y/dx^2 = (d^2y/du^2) (du/dx)^2$ is false.  I would prefer to write $\partial^2y/\partial{x}^2$ myself, on the grounds this is the coefficient on $dx^2$ in an expansion of $d^2y$ (in $d^2x$ and $dx^2$), analogous to the coefficients that are partial derivatives, rather than the ratio of $d^2y$ to $dx^2$.

Comment: @Toby Bartels: I've thought about this for a few days but I am still not sure what point you are trying to make.  Surely there IS a correct formula for the second derivative of a composite function, and there is a coherent theory of higher order differentials.

Comment: Yes, the correct chain rule for second derivatives is $d^2y/dx^2 = (d^2y/du^2)(du/dx)^2 + (dy/du)(d^2u/dx^2)$.  But unlike the chain rule for first derivatives, you can't derive this by treating $d^2y$ and the rest as if they were elements of an infinitesimal-enriched continuum obeying the ordinary rules of algebra.  At the very least, this is annoying (and I have found it so since since high school); but more than that, it suggests that the $dx^2$ that appears in $d^2y/dx^2$ is not really the square of $dx$ in such a continuum.

Comment: Good point.  Did you ever try seeing what Bos has to say about this?  See http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=469624

Answer (score 42):

The question is not precise enough to get a definite answer, but not for the reason most people say in commentaries. The problem does not lie in the ambiguous meaning of "consistent" (which just means
"free of contradictions", which was as clear then as now), but in the meaning of "way of arguing".
What we do have is a corpus of results from the founders of calculus (say Pascal, Descartes, Fermat, Newton, Leibniz), and a corpus of arguments they used to justify them. The corpus of results is certainly a corpus of true results, so is consistent,  and was certainly recognized as such even by Berkeley (to my knowledge, the first serious contradiction involving *results* of calculus
came 150 years after the founding period with Cauchy's theorem that a limit of continuous functions is continuous,
combined with counter-examples from Fourier's theory, so is completely out of our scope).

Now is the corpus of arguments used by our fathers "consistent"? This question does not make real sense, because "arguments" are not results, and are not "true or false", either individually or in groups. They are, then and now, incomplete developments aimed at convincing one's that some results are true. The thing one can say is that, however shaky the arguments seem to us, they were used by these founders to prove only true results.   In this very weak sense, their arguments were consistent.

Now, is the "way of arguing" of our fathers consistent? Again, the meaning of this question is problematic, because there is no unique way to deduce from a finite set of examples was what the 
"way or arguing" of our founding fathers. What is sure is that a naive reader of their arguments,
trying to guess, "by induction" in the sense of natural sciences, what was the *way of arguing* of these people, and trying to apply this way of arguing to get new results, 
would easily come across contradictions (even not so naive readers, such as Cauchy, 
eventually did so). Actually, it took almost 200 years for mathematicians to find a "consistent 
way of arguing" in which the arguments of the founder can be reformulated without too much distortion: it is the $\epsilon,\delta$ approach of Weierstrass and others. It took almost one more century to construct a second consistent approach, which perhaps has the slight advantage on the classical one to reformulate with even less 
distortion the arguing of the founders of calculus. Yet priority has a great weight in science, and this is the most obvious reason for which the non-standard analysis has not supplanted the traditional one.

I want to finish by a side, wittgensteinian,  remark: we are not in a qualitatively different 
situation than our founding fathers were: there is no way to be sure that our current "way of arguing"
is consistent, because there is no way to be sure what our current "way of arguing" exactly is.
By this I am not thinking at all at the problem that since Gödel we doubt that ZF or any other system is consistent, but to the much most basic problem that even with a "certainly consistent set of axioms" (say the axioms of the theory of groups,  to fix ideas), we are not really sure what our way of arguing (that is the logico-formal rules which allow us transform statements into other statements, from axioms to theorems)  is. To be sure, we mathematicians now take great care to begin a treatise
by explaining carefully those "formal rules" or reasoning. Yet this formal rules
use notions that are not completely clear (such as the notions of "intuitive integer") and skill that we can not be sure to posses (for example the capacity to recognize, in a finite expression, all occurrence of a given free variable). What we do is we see other people working using those rules,
we try to do the same by imitation, getting punished if we do it wrong, and after some times
do not make mistake anymore -- so we deduce that we understand the rules as the others do.
But there is no way to be really sure of that.

Comment: Dear Joel, Thanks for such a thoughtful answer.  Best wishes, Matt

Comment: For the most part I agree with your answer (except that I would mention Syntehtic Differential Geometry as the obvious modern resurrection of 17th-century calculus.) But if you're going to doubt that we can recognize all occurrences of free variables in a statement (and presumably so might computers) then won't we end up wallowing in a sea of despair? It is of course important to be aware of what out underlying assumptions are (such as "we can read"), but would it be really fruitful to stress over the fact that we do not live in a fantasy land?

Comment: Dear Andrej, I agree: my last paragraph is a little extreme, almost
falling into solipsism. What i wanted to say is that the *absoulte rigor* is never attained, and mathematical progress is done in two (infinite) directions at the same time. By improving the scope of 
our knowledge and by improving the rigor of our arguments.  

Comment: I do not take Joel's answer as an invitation to wallow in a sea of despair. I take it as a realistic description of what our brains do when learning and doing mathematics. There is no sure way of knowing what goes on in our wetware, but we are very good at doing whatever it is that we do.

Comment: @Joël: You wrote in your answer that "Now is the corpus of arguments used by our fathers 'consistent'? This question does not make real sense, because 'arguments' are not results, and are not 'true or false', either individually or in groups." It may be hard to speak of the consistency of their arguments since we have difficulty distinguishing between "consistency" and "rigor", but one can certainly ask whether historians like Dunham and Grabiner (see my comment above) are justified in speaking of their arguments as being INCONSISTENT. This is an ASSUMPTION whose roots are worth exploring.

Comment: Even Cauchy's mistake was arguably no mistake; it depends on what Cauchy meant by convergence (of a sequence of functions).  When presented with the counterexamples (which he knew well), Cauchy denied that they converged everywhere, because they failed to converge for certain *variable* quantities.  In particular, $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{sin(k x)}{k}$ fails to converge (in $n$) when $x$ is the infinitesimal variable $1/n$.  This is hard to interpret in either epsilontic analysis or nonstandard analysis, but it's not obviously inconsistent.

Comment: Toby expanded on his previous comment more thoroughly in the nLab: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy%27s+mistake

Comment: I don't take very seriously the assertion that "absolute rigor is never attained". Within libraries of formalized mathematics as mechanically checked by proof assistants like Coq and Mizar, I would say that absolute rigor is effectively attained in all but a pretty academic sense, or at least we could say that *improvements* in rigor over what has thus been attained are unlikely. The great 20th century achievement of the formalization of the logical calculus is not to be underestimated. 

Comment: @Toby Bartels: you wrote above that Cauchy's (1853) argument "is hard to interpret in either epsilontic analysis or nonstandard analysis, but it's not obviously inconsistent". I agree with you that Cauchy's argument is "not obviously inconsistent". Moreover, it does admit a straightforward formalisation in Robinson's framework. The point is to interpret Cauchy's $1/n$ as referring to a nonstandard point. Then the error term fails to tend to zero at this point, and Abel's counterexample is not a counterexample.  This was explained in our article http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10699-012-9285-8 p. 57

Comment: Toby, quite interesting post on Cauchy's mistake (or non-mistake).
I knew the analysis of this episode by Lakatos (whom I admire enormously, by the way) in Proofs and Refutations, but didn't know
he changed his position a few years laters on that subject. I will try to read his second text, as well as Cauchy's 1853 "fix of his proof". 

Comment: Lakatos is less of a Cauchy scholar than Laugwitz.  If you are looking for a treatment of Cauchy's error in Robinson's framework, I can suggest the following three papers by Laugwitz:
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?b=987515&b=921104&b=909630&batch_title=Selected%20Matches%20for:%20Author=(laugwitz)%20AND%20Anywhere=(cauchy)  And of course Robinson himself discussed this in detail in his book.

Comment: Robinson (whom Lakatos also read) interpreted Cauchy's infinitesimals as his infinitesimals (quite reasonably), how does one interpret _x_ = 1/_n_ precisely? (keeping in mind that this is the same _n_ as appears in the series).

Comment: @katz: I've read and liked your _Ten Misconceptions […]_ (which I cited at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/epsilontic+analysis too), but it didn't show me how to me interpret that example in nonstandard analysis.  (I actually expected you to agree that it doesn't work in nonstandard or epsilontic analysis, that either interpretation is ahistorical.)

Comment: Although I can vaguely see now how an interpretation in nonstandard analysis might go.  (Pick a single infinite integer _H_, then use both _n_ = _H_ and _x_ = 1/H.  Then the sum of sin(kx)/k, as _k_ goes from 1 to _n_, is not always infinitely close to 0.)  I'm not sure that this is a fair interpretation either, but at least it is an interpretation.

Comment: Last comment for Dr. Katz:  Can you tell me where page 57 in the Springer book corresponds to in the arXiv version?

Comment: See se. 6, particularly formula (6.2). This appears on p. 20 in arxiv. In modern terms, one considers the sequence (1/n) as representing an infinitesimal in the ultrapower construction. The latter depends on nonconstructive foundational material such as the existence of a maximal ideal, but if one is willing to settle for definable things only, one can construct everything without using any version (even weaker one) of the axiom of choice, as did Skolem in 1933-1934. I don't know if Cauchy would have liked Skolem's paper, but there is a good chance he would have found it comprehensible.

Comment: Yes, I don't really understand (6.2).  If this is supposed to state that $f_n$ converges (in $n$) to $f$ ‘everywhere’, then this should read ‘if $n$ infinite then $r_n(x)$ infinitesimal’ (where $r_n(x)$ was just defined as $f(x) - f_n(x)$), rather than ‘if $x$ infinitesimal then $r_n(x)$ infinitesimal’ as you wrote.  Choosing $x$ to be the infinitesimal $1/n$, of course, is the example that shows that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin(k x)}{k}$ fails to converge ‘everywhere’, but whether $x$ is infinitesimal doesn't go into the definition of convergence itself.

Comment: To my mind, the real problem with understanding what Cauchy means is that he talks about $f_n(x)$ converging to $f(x)$ ‘toujours’, and we want to interpret this as $\forall x, \Phi(x)$, where $n$ appears only as a *bound* variable in $\Phi(x)$ (which states that $f_n(x)$ converges in $n$ to $f(x)$).  To show explicitly that this is false, one proves $\exists x, \neg\Phi(x)$ by finding a specific $\xi$ and proving $\neg\Phi(\xi)$.  In this context, it makes no sense to use $1/n$ as $\xi$, since $n$ has no meaning outside of the formula $\Phi(x)$, yet the quantifier is outside.

Comment: It makes no difference whether one interprets $\forall x$ as meaning for every standard real number $x$ or for every hyperreal number $x$, or whatever.  Cauchy is not saying anything of the form $\forall x, \Phi(x)$ in the first place.  He is saying something more like $\forall n, \forall x, \Psi(x,n)$, where $\Psi(x,n)$ states my correction to (6.2): ‘if $n$ infinite then $r_n(x)$ infinitesimal’.  I'm not sure that even this correctly interprets what he meant, but at least it allows one to meaningfully substitute $1/n$ for $x$.

Comment: Condition P1= "for x infinitesimal" is a special case of condition P2= "for all x". Therefore if a series violates P1, it will violate P2 as well. Cauchy showed that the "counterexample" violates P1, and therefore is not a counterexample if the hypothesis of convergence is interpreted as applying at ALL points and not merely at real points. Thus, Cauchy's 1853 text cannot be interpreted as introducing a condition of uniform convergence (as has been claimed by historians) UNLESS one also interprets him as using an extended number system (which the said historians are reluctant to do).

Comment: Sure, I agree with that.  But I still don't understand why you write (6.2) in that way.  (And it still needs the clause ‘for $n$ infinite’, otherwise there is no reason why $r_n(x)$ should ever be infinitesimal.)  And it doesn't help me understand how $1/n$ makes sense as a possible value of $x$ in a context where $n$ has yet to appear.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  I wrote (6.2) that way because that's the nature of Cauchy's counterexample to Abel's counterexample: the condition is violated at the infinitesimal 1/n.  Granted, Cauchy here is not crystal clear, but at least an infinitesimal-enriched framework allows one to formalize Cauchy's 1853 argument, which is not at all possible in standard analysis.

Comment: You offered that formula (apparently on page 57 of the Springer version) as an explanation of the ‘straightforward formalisation’ in Robinson's nonstandard analysis of Cauchy's $x = 1/n$ counterexample to the claim that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{sin(k x)}{k}$ converges everywhere, which I had said was difficult to do.  And although I put forth a possible formalisation in a later comment, I don't think that it's straightforward, and (6.2) doesn't help.

Comment: And I still think that (6.2) is missing the hypothesis that $n$ is infinite; it must be implicit.  The way that it's phrased, it really makes it look like $r_n(x)$ is only required to be infinitesimal when $x$ is infinitesimal, which of course is not the case; but it is the case that $r_n(x)$ is only required to be infinitesimal when $n$ is infinite.  So at best, it is confusingly written, although now that you've explained why you wrote it that way, I can understand it.  (But earlier I really thought that you had meant to write ‘$n$ infinite’ and had written ‘$x$ infinitesimal’ by mistake.)

Comment: I appreciate your interest in this item of math history.  If you get around to writing up a presentation of the hyperreal formalisation of Cauchy's 1853 argument that meets your standards, please let me know.  I think this would be a worthwhile thing to do, particularly since you already have a website on this.  Perhaps we can continue the rest of this conversation via email because the benefit to the rest of the readers is becoming infinitesimal :-)

Comment: OK, if I write anything up carefully, I'll put it at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+sum+theorem (or at least somewhere easily available from there) and put a note here in case anybody else is still following along later, but otherwise I will keep it to private email.

Answer (score 17):

Contrary to Andrej Bauer’s contention, seventeenth-century calculus looks very little like SDG. Unlike in SDG, the integrals were construed as infinite sums, the intermediate value theorem was assumed to hold for continuous curves and, more to the point, for the most part the infinitesimals that were employed were invertible rather than nilpotent. For a while, the Dutch mathematician, Bernard Nieuwentijt, in his debate with Leibniz, argued in favor of the use of nilpotent infinitesimals, but eventually came to believe that his attack on Leibniz was ill-founded and returned to the then standard use of invertible infinitesimals. Of course, I’m not suggesting that nilpotent infinitesimals were not used—they were from time to time—but only that their use was not the main view. After all, following Leibniz, most mathematicians wanted their infinitesimals to behave like real numbers.

Nilpotent infinitesimals along with invertible infinitesimals were employed by a number of differential geometers in the nineteenth century and entered mainstream mathematics around the turn of the twentieth-century (in systems of dual numbers), when geometers such as Hjelmslev and Segre became interested in geometries in which two points need not determine a unique straight line, and Grothendieck (and others) later employed them in algebraic geometry.

I suspect that the misconception that seventeenth-century calculus looks like SDG can be traced in part to John Bell’s wonderful expository writings on SDG. Bell was taken to task for this by the historian-mathematician Detlef Laugwitz in his otherwise very positive review (for Mathematical Reviews MR1646123 (99h:00002)) of the first edition of Bell's A Primer of Infinitesimal Analysis (1998). Moreover, I am not aware of any of the many serious writings on the history of the calculus that supports the view suggested by (my friend) John.

Response to Mikhail Katz:

Mikhail: Fermat’s work was one I had in mind when I said nilpotent infinitesimals were used from time to time. However, his work, which was largely concerned with tangent constructions and lacked generality, predates the work of Newton and Leibniz, never caught on, and is not characteristic of the mainstream approaches to the calculus of the 17th century, which is what I said I was talking about. Moreover, Fermat’s work is notoriously unclear and, by my lights, the similarities with SDG are vague at best.

Many thanks, however, for the reference to Cifoletti’s work, which I will take a look at. I hasten to add, however, that the following passage from the Mathematical Reviews review of the work, which you yourself cite, does not inspire confidence.

“In the second part of the book, the author embarks on an investigation of the link between modern synthetic differential geometry, originally proposed by F. W. Lawvere in 1967 and afterwards largely developed by Lawvere and other mathematicians, and Fermat's mathematics.

In many situations, for the most part informal ones, Lawvere himself and other mathematicians working in this research field expressed their feelings that there had to be some kind of affinity between synthetic differential geometry and seventeenth-century mathematical practice. The author has tried to make explicit these general feelings, but this part of the book is mathematically weak and somewhat naive.

The best example is footnote 29, page 208, where the author claims to have established a direct connection between Fermat and synthetic differential geometry, on the basis of having been able to convince G. Rejes, during a talk she had with him about Fermat's work, to name a particular axiom of one possible formulation of the theory after Fermat.”

Comment: I haven't read it, but Bell later published *The Continuous and the Infinitesimal in Mathematics and Philosophy* where he discusses the history of infinitesimals, perhaps in an attempt to correct the unbalanced account in his *Primer of Infinitesimal Analysis*.

Comment: I do not believe John goes far toward correcting the misconception in his book "The Continuous and the Infinitesimal in Mathematics and Philosophy." Moreover, he continues to perpetuate the misconception in the Second Edition of his Primer, which came out three years after the just-named book. For my review of John's "The Continuous ...," see The Bulletin of Symbolic Logic 13 (2007), no. 3, pp. 361-363.-Philip Ehrlich

Comment: Very nice answer. 

Comment: The 1990 book "Fermat's method: its status and diffusion" by Cifoletti (reviewed here: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1160157) arguably belongs to "serious writings on the history of the calculus that supports the view" that Smooth Differential Geometry (SDG) of Lawvere and others is a plausible formalisation of the 17th century work of Fermat. 

Comment: Mikhail: Thanks for your comment. See my edit for my response, which is too long for a comment.

Comment: I examined Cifoletti's footnote 29 on page 208 in detail a few months ago, and did not find anything objectionable.  My conclusion was that the remark by the mathscinet reviewer is a odious misrepresentation of what Cifoletti actually wrote.

Answer (score 15):

I found a copy of the relevant passage from Berkeley's works at [this web site](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Berkeley/Analyst/Analyst.html). I have cut and pasted from that site, and I have reformatted the mathematics; apologies to the good Bishop for any alterations in meaning.

> XIV. To make this Point plainer, I shall unfold the reasoning, and propose it in a fuller light to your View. It amounts therefore to this, or may in other Words be thus expressed. I suppose that the Quantity $x$ flows, and by flowing is increased, and its Increment I call $o$, so that by flowing it becomes $x + o$. And as $x$ increaseth, it follows that every Power of $x$ is likewise increased in a due Proportion. Therefore as $x$ becomes $x + o$, $x^n$ will become $(x + o)^n$: that is, according to the Method of infinite Series,
>   $$x^n + nox^{n-1} + \frac{n^2-n}{2} o^2 x^{n-2} + \text{  etc.}$$
>   And if from the two augmented Quantities we subduct the Root and the Power respectively, we shall have remaining the two Increments, to wit,
>   $$o  \text{  and  }  nox^{n-1} + \frac{n^2-n}{2} o^2 x^{n-2} + \text{  etc.}$$
>   which Increments, being both divided by the common Divisor o, yield the Quotients
>   $$1 \text{  and  } nx^{n-1} + \frac{n^2-n}{2} ox^{n-2} + \text{  etc.}$$ 
>   which are therefore Exponents of the Ratio of the Increments. Hitherto I have supposed that $x$ flows, that $x$ hath a real Increment, that $o$ is something. And I have proceeded all along on that Supposition, without which I should not have been able to have made so much as one single Step. From that Supposition it is that I get at the Increment of $x^n$, that I am able to compare it with the Increment of $x$, and that I find the Proportion between the two Increments. I now beg leave to make a new Supposition contrary to the first, i. e. I will suppose that there is no Increment of $x$, or that $o$ is nothing; which second Supposition destroys my first, and is inconsistent with it, and therefore with every thing that supposeth it. I do nevertheless beg leave to retain $nx^{n - 1}$, which is an Expression obtained in virtue of my first Supposition, which necessarily presupposeth such Supposition, and which could not be obtained without it: All which seems a most inconsistent way of arguing, and such as would not be allowed of in Divinity.

It looks to me that Berkeley's argument amounts to an argument raised by every discerning student in a nonrigorous first semester calculus course: ``Is the increment zero? or not zero? How can it be both? That's inconsistent!'' In which case I would invite the good Bishop to come to my office hours where I would introduce him to $\epsilon$, $\delta$ proofs.

I bet I could even convince the Bishop that Divinity would allow it: "Suppose the Devil gives you any $\epsilon > 0$. This $\epsilon$, although positive, might be very, very, very small, as small as the Devil likes...".

Comment: See my answer for transcription of the argument into modern syntetic differential analysis.

Comment: @Lee: if you get the Bishop in your office, see if Dr. Johnson is also free to join in the discussion...

Comment: @Lee Mosher: Every discerning student would ask such a question, and we generally have answers. But Leibniz arguably already had an answer to Berkeley's question. The answer is given by Leibniz's Transcendental Law of Homogeneity. This allows one to discard $dx$ without setting it equal to zero. What Hewitt, Los, and Robinson showed is that Leibniz can be formalized even without $\epsilon,\delta$. There is a debate going on about this but the math community can form its own opinion rather than relying on historians which often operate with outdated conceptual frameworks inadequate to the task.

Answer (score 13):

I do not know whether the early calculus was consistent, but it surely *can* be made as consistent as modern mathematics, with practically no modifications of the basic setup. This goes under the name [Synthetic differential geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_differential_geometry) (SDG). Like Robinson's [nonstandard analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis) it is a calculus with infinitesimals. SDG should be closer to the 17th century ways of doing things because it works with *nilpotent* infinitesimals whereas nonstandard analysis does not. I believe the 17th century calculus used nilpotent infinitesimals. Can someone confirm this?

---

[**Edit:** many thanks to Lee Mosher for transcribing a piece of Berkeley's text. Here is the same piece of text, as it would be written in SDG in the 21st century.]

> We would like to compute the derivative of $f(x) = x^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer.
>   Let $x \in R$ and let $o$ be any nilpotent infinitesimal of degree 2. Then by the Binomial theorem
>   $$(x + o)^n = x^n + n o x^{n-1} + \frac{n^2 - n}{2} o^2 x^{n-2} + \text{etc}.$$
>   Because $o$ is nilpotent of degree 2, we have $o^2 = 0$ and so all terms but the first two equal zero. Thus we get
>   $$(x + o)^n = x^n + n o x^{n-1}$$
>   hence
>   $$(x + o)^n - x^n = n o x^{n-1}$$
>   or
>   $$f(x + o) - f(x) = n x^{n-1} o$$
>   Because $o$ here is an arbitrary infinitesimal (i.e., the equation holds for all $o$ whose square iz zero), we may use the Axiom of Microaffinity to conclude that
>   $$f'(x) o = n x^{n-1} o$$
>   Now we use the Cancelation Principle to cancel $o$ on both sides, which yields $f'(x) = n x^{n-1}$.

I must say Berkeley's writting was a great deal more picturesque. The Axiom of Microaffinity and the Cancelation Principle are an axiom and a theorem of SDG, respectively. They circumvent the problem that Berkeley was complaining about, namely that first we pretend that $o$ is not zero (so that we can cancel it on both sides of equation), but then we pretend it is zero so that all those higher terms disappear. Instead, we can do the following: assume that $o^2 = 0$ (which does *not* imply that $o = 0$ because we are not assuming classical logic) so that the higher terms disappear, but then use a sort of weak cancelation property of infinitesimals which allows us to cancel them under certain conditions, even though they are not invertible.

**Axiom of Microaffinity:** For every $f : R \to R$ and $x \in R$ there exists a unique number $f'(x)$, called *the derivative* of $f$ at $x$, such that for all infinitesimals $o$ we have $f(x + o) - f(x) = f'(x) o$.

**Cancelation principle:** Let $a, b \in R$. If $a \cdot o = b \cdot o$ for all $o \in \Delta$ then $a = b$.

Is this weird? Yes, it sure is if you are classically trained. It gets weirder: if we let $\Delta = \lbrace o \in R \mid o^2 = 0 \rbrace$ be the set of square-nilpotent infinitesimals then

1. Potentially there exist non-zero infinitesimals: $\lnot \forall o \in \Delta, o = 0$.
2. There are no infinitesimals which are distinct from zero: $\lnot \exists o \in \Delta, o \neq 0$.

But it is *precisely* what we need to explain all the confusion about infinitesimals. Remember it this way: potentially there are some non-zero ones (we cannot exclude their existence) but they are all potentially zero (they are so small we cannot distinguish them from zero). Just don't ask yourself whether an infinitesimal is zero and all will be fine.

Here $R$ is the "smooth real line", which is an ordered field. Of course, it does not satisfy the Archimedean axiom, as that would force all infinitesimals to be zero. So it is a different kind of animal than the usual $\mathbb{R}$.

John Bell explained all this in his excellent booklet on Syntehtic Differential Analysis.

Comment: I don't know but it's an interesting question. I can't imagine 17th century mathematicians writing $dx^2 = 0$ but I can imagine them writing $(x+dx)^2 = x^2 + 2xdx$.

Comment: But if they write $(x + dx)^2 = x^2 + 2 x dx$ then it follows immediately by basic algebra that $dx^2 = 0$. *Why of why* didn't they just follow their noses?

Comment: Newton, for one, did exactly as I said. "Thus, for example, in the case of the fluent $z = x^n$, Newton first forms $\dot{z} + \dot{zo} = (\dot{x} + \dot{xo})^n$, expands the right-hand side using the binomial theorem, subtracts $z = x^n$, divides through by $o$, neglects all terms still containing $o$, and so obtains $\dot{z} = nx^{n−1}\dot{x}." (From section 4 of http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/continuity/ )

Comment: However, Leibniz had a different take: "He also assumed that the $n$th power $(dx)^n$ of a first-order differential was of the same order of magnitude as an $n$th-order differential $d^nx$, in the sense that the quotient $d^nx/(dx)^n$ is a finite quantity." (Same source.)

Comment: L'Hôpital saw that $dxdy = 0$ follows from his first postulate: "Grant that two quantities, whose difference is an infinitely small quantity, may be taken (or used) indifferently for each other: or (what is the same thing) that a quantity, which is increased or decreased only by an infinitely small quantity, may be considered as remaining the same." (Same source.)

Comment: @François G. Dorais: you wrote above that "I can't imagine 17th century mathematicians writing $dx^2=0$".  I would like to comment that 17th century mathematician Nieuwentijt did explicitly envision nilsquare infinitesimals.  Bell mentions this in his piece "continuity and infinitesimals" at SEP.  However, Leibniz proceeded differently.

Comment: It might have been more interesting if L'Hôpital had calculated that $dx\,dy + dy\,dx = 0$, then concluded that $dx\,dy = −dy\,dx$ rather than that $dx\,dy = 0$.

Answer (score 7):

I would agree with Alexandre Eremenko's answer. The early calculus in fact was not inconsistent, as elaborated below.

Joël's answer is based on a premise that "the question is not precise enough to get a definite answer", and "does not make real sense, because 'arguments' are not results". This premise is historically incorrect. In fact, in the historical literature the claim of inconsistency of the early calculus is very specific and precise. It is routinely based on Berkeley's analysis of the typical calculations such as that of the derivative of a power, or the derivative of the product of two functions. The alleged inconsistency is presented as follows. Berkeley claims that (1) $dx$ is nonzero at the start of the calculation; (2) $dx$ is assumed to be zero at its conclusion; (3) in any consistent reasoning, $dx$ cannot be simultaneously zero and nonzero; (4) therefore the procedures of the calculus were inconsistent, Q.E.D. In modern notation, this amounts to a claimed inconsistency of the type $(dx\not=0)\wedge(dx=0)$.

Berkeley, however, did not read Leibniz carefully enough. Leibniz explicitly and repeatedly clarifies that he is working with a generalized notion of equality, where expressions equal up to a negligible term are also held to be equal. In modern terminology, this means that Leibniz is working with a binary relation which is not equality on the nose, but rather approximate equality in a suitable sense. It is in this sense that Leibniz writes formulas like $2x+dx=2x$ (note that he did not use our "=" symbol). Leibniz might not have been "rigorous" by modern standards, but he was not inconsistent, either. In fact, Leibniz's procedures were more soundly based than Berkeley's criticisms thereof. Philosopher David Sherry and I presented our analysis last year in the Notices of the AMS at http://www.ams.org/notices/201211/

Felix Klein wrote in 1908 that there were in fact not one but two separate tracks for the development of analysis: (A) the Weierstrassian one, in the context of an Archimedean continuum; and (B) the track exploiting indivisibles and/or infinitesimals. The B-track was eventually popularized by Abraham Robinson.

Everybody is familiar with the great accomplishment of Weierstrass in developing rigorous foundations for analysis, which is beyond dispute. However, historian Carl Boyer (and many others), in describing Cantor, Dedekind, and Weierstrass as "the great triumvirate", adds an anti-infinitesimal spin to their accomplishment. Namely, the traditional historical literature seeks to couple their "rigorous" accomplishment to the elimination of "inconsistent" infinitesimals, as if pursuing the A-track depended on the elimination of the B-track (Dunham's "rotten foundations"). It is the coupling of Weierstrass's accomplishment to an ill-informed critique of infinitesimals (both classical and modern) that constitutes the historical misconception pointed out by Vickers and others.

Comment: I have mixed feelings about this entire thread. On the one hand, I am now aware of various papers written by katz et al. I have previously read a lot of Dunham, Grabiner, etc, and it is good to see a counterpoint to their position. However, I feel that the question was posed by katz merely as an excuse to give the above answer (with a personal citation). katz's previously closed post supports this. I find this frustrating, and it dampens my interest in katz's papers. If this is the case, I hope katz will take a different approach in the future. If not, I'll be glad to hear otherwise.

Comment: @Ben Brown: As you point out (with sources), the received historical scholarship views the early calculus as inconsistent.  There is an opposing minority view, including the article by Vickers. A sought to formulate my question in a balanced way as I don't happen to believe that I have a monopoly on historical truth.  The question led to a fruitful discussion as evidenced by the 7 answers given.  The issue of (in)consistency of the early calculus is merely the tip of the iceberg; many other issues were raised at...

Comment: ... [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445166/is-mathematical-history-written-by-the-victors) (response to @Ben)

Answer (score 6):

As it was noted by Ryan Budney and  Lee Mosher and Ben Braun, the word "consistent" cannot be
used here in the sense of modern mathematical logic. So one cannot investigate this question
rigorously. But one can apply the word "consistent" with its everyday (fuzzy) sense,
meaning "free of contradictions". Then the answer is to some extent a question of opinion.

Myself I side with the opinion of Peter Vickers: early calculus was consistent. It was not 
worse than arguments in most other hard sciences (physics, chemistry). But perhaps not
on the level of rigor of Mathematics.

On the other hand, what Berkeley says "a most inconsistent way of arguing, and such as would not be allowed in Divinity" sounds ridiculous to me. "Divinity" is a pseudo-science which deals with
the things that do not exist; thus what is "allowed" in Divinity or not allowed
is completely a matter of opinion. Divinity cannot be compared with other hard sciences,
while mathematics of Newton (or Leibnitz or Euler) can.

Comment: "Divinity" for Berkeley in this sentence has the sense of whatever makes that each's person's sensations are consistent with each other's. Call it "matter" if you prefer. 

Comment: Divinity may be a study of things that do not exist (although obviously Berkeley himself believed otherwise), but that goes into the premises, which have always been very questionable.  But the mode of reasoning was by scholastic logic, which we would regard even today as perfectly rigorous.

Comment: If we identify "Divinity" with theology, then no theologian I know disputes that it is not a science in the modern sense of the empirical sciences. But then, neither is mathematics. They will however claim, or some will, that it is a science in the Aristotelian sense. As far as dealing "with the things that do not exist", your opinion is duly noted, but unless you are a Platonist, mathematicians inevitably deal with objects with no extra-mental existence. And since mathematical objects are abstract, not localized in space-time, empirical considerations are of little avail to him.

Comment: G. Rodrigues: 1. Yes, mathematics is not a science like physics or geology, but it is on the "opposite side" from theology. In the sense
that it is more consistent, and the truth proved mathematically has
somehow higher status than a scientific truth. (In what sense statement of theology/divinity can be considered true, I don't know.
Or what is the criterion of truth in theology:-)

2. Yes, I am a strong Platonist. And frankly speaking it is hard 
for me to imagine how a working mathematician can be something else, though I know that some mathematicians profess other views. 

Comment: I would question the claim that "the word 'consistent' cannot be used here in the sense of modern mathematical logic". Berkeley claimed that the calculus was based on the inconsistency $(dx\not=0)\wedge(dx=0)$. Arguably this is the same meaning as in modern logic.

Comment: Toby Bartels: you wrote: "scholastic logic, which we would regard even today as perfectly rigorous". Who are "we"?

Answer (score 4):

I think that the question is sufficiently precise if we think at a **realistic** meaning of the word “inconsistent”. Also nowadays, for non logicians the adjective “inconsistent” doesn't really mean “free of contradictions” (this is only the obvious meaning given by modern Mathematical Logic), but rather it means **not acceptable by a large or important part of the scientific community**.

Also nowadays, some of our works in some parts of modern Mathematics are not accepted as sufficiently rigorous by other parts. These works are hence perceived only as not sufficiently precise “ways of arguing”. Therefore, these “foreign argumentations” are perceived as potentially inconsistent, and need a different reformulation to be accepted. I know of relationships of this type between some parts of Geometry and Analysis, to mention only an example. It is the same problem occurring in the relationships between (some parts of) Physics and Mathematics because these two disciplines are really completely different “games”: in Physics the most important achievement is the existence of a dialectic between formulas and a part of nature, even if the related Mathematics lacks in formal clarity and is hence not accepted by several mathematicians.

Analogously, early calculus was consistent until the community accepted these “ways of arguing” and discovered statements which could be verified as true by a dialogue with other part of knowledge: Physics and geometrical intuition in primis.

Since in the early calculus the formal intuition (in the modern sense of manipulation of symbols, without a reference to intuition) was surely weak, the dialectic between proofs and intuition was surely stronger (I mean statistically, in the distribution of 17th century mathematicians). In my opinion, this is the reason of the discovering of true statements, even if the related proofs are perceived as “weak” nowadays. Once the great triumvirate Cantor, Dedekind, and Weierstrass decided that it was time to make a step further, the notion of “inconsistent” changed for this important part of the community and hence, sooner or later, for all the others.

Also from the point of view of rules of inference, the consistency of early calculus has to be meant in the sense of dialectic between different parts of knowledge and acceptance by the related scientific community.

Therefore, in this sense, in my opinion early calculus is as consistent as our (and the future) calculus.

I agree with Joel that “we are not in a qualitatively different situation”: probably in the near future all proofs will be computer assisted, in the sense that all the missing steps will be checked by a computer (whose software will be verified, once again, by a large part of the community) and we will only need to provide the main steps. Necessarily, articles will change in nature and, I hope, they will be more focused on those ideas and intuitions thanks to which we were able to create the results we are presenting. Therefore, young students in the future will probably read disgusted at our papers saying: “how were they able to understand how all these results were created? These papers seems like phone books: def, lem, thm, cor, def, lem, thm, cor... without any explanation of discovery rules and several missing formal steps!”.

Finally, I think that only formally, but not conceptually, this early calculus may look similar to NSA or SDG. In my opinion, one of the main reason of the lack of diffusion of NSA is that its techniques are perceived as “voodoo” by all modern mathematicians (the majority) that rely their work on the dialogue between formal mathematics and informal intuition. Too much frequently the lack of intuition is too strong in both theories. For example, for a person like Cauchy, what is the intuitive meaning of the standard part of the sine of an infinite number (NSA)? For people like Bernoulli, what is the intuitive meaning of properties like $x\le0$
  and $x\ge0$
  for every infinitesimal and $\neg\neg\exists h$
  such that $h$
  is infinitesimal (but not necessarily there exists an infinitesimal; SDG)? Moreover, as soon as discontinuous functions appeared in the calculus, the natural reactions of almost every working mathematicians (of 17th century **and nowadays**) looking at the microaffinity axiom is not to change Logic switching to the intuitionistic one, but to change this axiom inserting a restriction on the quantifier “for every $f:R\longrightarrow R$”.

The apparently inconsistent argumentation of setting $h\ne0$
  and finally $h=0$, can be faithfully formalized using classical calculus rather than using these theories of infinitesimals. We can say that $f:R\longrightarrow R$ (here $R$
  is the usual Archimedean real field) is differentiable at $x$
  if there exists a function $r:R\times R\longrightarrow R$
  such that $f(x+h)=f(x)+h\cdot r(x,h)$
  and such that $r$
  is continuous at $h=0$. It is easy to prove that this function $r$
  is unique. Therefore, we can assume $h\ne0$, we can make freely calculations to discover what is the unique form of the function $r(x,h)$ for $h\ne0$ and, in the final formula, to set $h=0$ because $r$ is clearly continuous for all the examples of functions of the early calculus. This is called the Fermat-Reyes methods, and it can be proved also for generalized functions like Schwartz distributions (and hence for an isomorphic copy of the space of all the continuous functions). Moreover, in my opinion, both Cauchy and Bernoulli would had perfectly understood this method and the related intuition. On the contrary, they would not be able to understand all the intuitive inconsistencies they can easily find both in NSA and SDG.

Comment: Technicality: Say that $r$ is continuous *in $h$* when $h = 0$.  (To require $r$ to be jointly continuous when $h = 0$ makes $f$ continuously differentiable, not just differentiable.)

Comment: I don't agree with the opening paragraph of this answer.  "Consistent" is a perfectly clear English word that means, in this context, "not self-contradictory".  If a person is inconsistent, they are not saying or doing the same things over time.

Answer (score 1):

The completeness of the real number implies that there are no infinitesimals. If $\epsilon$ is infinitesimal, then $n\epsilon<1$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. This bounded increasing sequence has no least upper bound, although it should by completeness.

In the form of *Archimedes' axiom*, completeness has been a part of mathematics since ancient times. Archimedes himself used it to solve some problems of calculus. I always thought that Berkeley spotted this inconsistency and rightfully complained about it.

Comment: This is not the only kind of completeness possible.

Comment: But it is the kind that Berkeley would have had in mind.

Comment: The completeness axiom is for *real* numbers. Are infinitesimal quantities real?

Comment: I guess that would hard to say in Newtons and Leibniz's work, because they never talked about real numbers. For nonstandard arithmetic and synthetic differential geometry, the answer is: yes. In those cases, completeness is subtly weakened to allow infinitesimal real numbers.

Comment: From what I read, Leibniz was well aware that if infinitesimals were real then the Archimedean property would fail. It appears that he resolved this by thinking of infinitesimals as variable quantities rather than constant quantities. His followers had a variety of different views. For example, L'Hôpital maintained that two quantities that differ by an infinitesimal amount are indistinguishable. In that case, $n\epsilon$ is not increasing and therefore does not contradict the completeness of the real numbers. Johann Bernoulli, on the other hand, believed that infinitesimals are very real.

Comment: I think the distinction between real and not real was actually pretty common at the time. This was very clear when algebraic arguments used imaginary quantities, where the authors would always apologize profusely for using such objects. Infinitesimals are a different beast but it is certainly not beyond 17th century mathematicians to distinguish them from real quantities. There appears to have been a variety of different views about this as detailed here: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/continuity/

Comment: Actually as far as Leibniz was concerned infinitesimals were not at all "a different beast" as compared to imaginaries.  On the contrary, he explicitly and repeatedly compares infinitesimals and imaginaries in seeking to justify his techniques.  Of course, Leibniz's notion of "ordinary" number was not identical with our modern notion of "real number", either.

Comment: @Wouter Stekelenburg: The notion that what "Berkeley had in mind" was our "complete Archimedean continuum" is a historical misconception. Just the opposite: Berkeley fiercely opposed the idea of an indefinitely divisible continuum that we take for granted today. In line with his empiricist philosophy, Berkeley postulated an empirical "minimum" M below which nothing meaningful can exist: sort of "if you can't see it, it can't exist". His opposition to a divisible continuum and his opposition to infinitesimals were made of the same cloth.

Comment: The main person pushing this view of the continuum today seems to be Doron Zeilberger.  It is a sort of ultrafinitism.

Comment: Then what we have here is a Berkeley-Zeilberger discretized continuum, which is certainly a legitimate and fascinating object in its own right.  However, it wasn't Leibniz's continuum.  This puts into question the relevance of Berkeley's critique. Another critical analysis of Berkeley's text by Andersen can be found at http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.hm.2010.07.001


Comment: Toby: how articulated is Zeilberger's view? Have his views been developed mathematically, starting with axioms and proving theorems? (Although something about that doesn't sound like something he would carry out.) 


Comment: Todd:  As far as I know, no.  But one should ask him.

Comment: There is an issue in modern treatments of infinitesimals that is easy to miss: in order to match the modern concept that the real line is archimedean (e.g. that the sequence $1/n$ converges to $0$), they abandon the argument that infinitesimals are "real". Instead infinitesimals are, like non-real complex numbers, just some additional objects that can sometimes be used to verify properties of the reals.

Comment: @Carl: the fact that the analysis over  $^∗\mathbb{R}$  is generally concerned with internal sets and functions rather than arbitrary sets and functions indicates that it is not the continuum per se that's of interest but rather its applications. The Basel problem is a great example. Euler was interested in establishing a real relation $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, but the proofs he gave typically pass via infinitesimals, infinite numbers, and the associated infinite products. The object of interest is the interesting identity rather than the infinitary numbers themselves.

Comment: The interest in identities was likely true for Euler, and other mathematicians before the 19th century. But it is now more common to think that *structures* are the key focus of contemporary mathematics (considering both the dominant platonistic approach and in the less-common structualist approach).

Comment: @Carl: I would interpret the idea that "structures are the key" as saying that epistemological issues, or perhaps syntactic issues, are the key focus, as opposed to ontological or semantic issues. This does not contradict at all the idea that continua (whether Archimedean or Bernoullian) are of less interest than structural results of which the Basel is an elementary example.

Comment: I do believe it contradicts that. The contemporary approach to mathematics is extremely semantic (perhaps it could be summarized with the motto "the goal of mathematicians is to study mathematical structures to understand the properties of those structures"). A general resistance to syntacticism is visible throughout contemporary mathematics, beginning with elementary calculus and extending through research-level work. Examples include the preference for bijective proofs of combinatorial identities, and the aversion to formal logic because of a perceived "excessive" focus on syntax.

Comment: @Carl: these fine points of philosophy will have to be settled elsewhere, but regardless of how you interpret "structures", it is clear that the NSA community views new results as being of paramount interest (such as Goldbring's proof of local version of Hilbert's 5th problem), rather than the study of ${}^*\mathbb{R}$ itself. In this "result-focused" approach they follow an ancient tradition starting with Fermat, Leibniz, Euler, Cauchy, and others.

Comment: @Carl: I am interested in your view of the semantic/syntactic distinction in modern mathematics. Is this developed anywhere in more detail? You seem to interpret this distinction as a motivation for focusing on R at the expense of other continua, but such an approach strikes me as more akin to foundationalism, which seems to be thought of as the opposite of structuralism.